# copy constructor+assignment operator

Tags: c++, lint

This is a part of my code ....
//samlple.h........

```
class Manager{            
public:                                                
    Manager(cmd::Processor *cp);                    
    virtual ~Manager(void);                                
protected:                                       
    cmd::Processor  *m_Processor;                                       

};
```

//samlple.cpp........

```
//Default constructor                  

Manager::Manager(                
    cmd::Processor  *cp           
) : m_commandProcessor(cp)                
    {            
    g_MgrCommand = new MgrCommand(this);                
}
```

After running this I am getting the below warning :
Sample.cpp(97): Info 1732: new in constructor for class 'Manager' which has no assignment operator ........

I am new to c++ coding ...
Can you tell me how can I write copy constructor and assignment operator for my class to remove this warning

Comment: rule of three (or five)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an `operator=` member function:

```
Manager& Manager::operator=(const Manager&) {
    // ...
    return (*this);
}
```

Of course the first argument of the function can be anything you want it to be.

Comment: where I can write the above declaration : in public or protected area ??

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement the copy c'tor/assignment.

The point is that, unless you implement them yourself, the compiler implements it automatically by member-wise copy. In your specific case this auto-generated code will be incorrect, since you'll have several objects pointing to the same allocated `MgrCommand`.

You should either implement the c'tor/assignment operator correctly (probably by allocating a separate instance of `MgrCommand` in every object), or **disable** them.

Comment: I have this warning also in code : Info 1733: new in constructor for class 'Manager' which has no copy constructor